# How to pass table record identifier to client side

Tags: javascript, html, database, security, privacy

In a CRUD environment, let say we are displaying list of user's contacts. Web site needs to provide "Edit" and "Delete" functionality to user. Each contact represents a record in database table, and identifier of a record must be passed to browser (client).

In my applications, I normally have an auto increment identifier field in table and I pass its value to browser. So when user wants to edit or delete, I send request to server together with that identifier. In that way I can find the record in table.

But I am worried about security and privacy. Normally I do not allow any other user to access someone else's record (Duh), though still do not like passing just an integer number to browser.

AFAIK, big companies are providing a long unique identifier like 40F0C923BACECBF40C4CAA465D0E4DB0 to do this, but this time I will need to check if that value is used before every time I create a new record.

I didn't know where to ask this question to Database section or here, and just asked here.
How do you guys manage to do this? or in other words, how it is done professionally?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an OWASP top 10 violation.  Specifically [Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).  Every database record needs to have an ownership id.  Such that you can store the user's id in the session state and make sure that the user is accessing a record that belongs to them.

Comment: I do that already. Before doing anything about database, firstly ownership is checked. But what I wonder is that if passing just record identifier integer number to browser is a professional technique?